# Anonymous authentication error in flutter iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm having an error using firebase anonymous auth on iOS part of flutter app, I don't have any error on android using this same firebase anonymous auth. My implementation of anonymous auth on AppDelegate.swift is like this:

```
let auth = Auth.auth()
auth.signInAnonymously { (authResult, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("There was some network authenticating error")
        return
    }
    guard let user = authResult?.user else { return }
    let isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous  // true
    let uid = user.uid
 

}
```

While debugging the app it launches normally without any error, then on flutter when I try to use the authentication anonymous it returns null, this is the line involved:

```
UserCredential userCredential =
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
```

As a result of this null user credential when I try to upload a file to firebase it returns the error that user is not authorized to do this. I repeat on android I don't have this problem, any idea why this might be?

Comment: If you print `err`, what does it output?

Comment: it doesnt print anything, the error message i get when trying to upload a file is `[firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action` . Any idea on how to implement this anonymous auth correctly on the swift file?

Comment: None of the code you shared accesses Firebase Storage, so it can't be raising this error. It sounds like you'd benefit from reading how to implement the server side security rules for Cloud Storage though, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security and https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules. If you're still having trouble after that, edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show the [minimal code and security rules with which any of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read that link too please, as it's quite useful).